# Problem with saving/updating Object in MongoDB using Laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I'm attempting to track changes in a document. Whenever the user makes a change to the document, their user id/time of the change gets logged. I want to keep the log history, so I'm attempting to append to my `change_log` field in Mongo. The problem is that creating an associative array in mongo using the PHP adapter automatically creates the field as an object. It being an object is precluding me from using `$desk->push()` to add to it, and if I attempt to use `$desk->update()` the code returns a type error. I'm hoping to either find a way to force mongo to save this as an array (don't think it's possible) or to find a way to reset the object without type errors. Thanks in advance.

```
if (isset($desk->change_log)) {
                $change_log_data = $desk->change_log;
                $change_log_data[] = [
                    'user_id' => $post['user_id'], 'date' => $date
                ];
                $desk->update('change_log', $change_log_data);
            } else {
                $desk->change_log = ['user_id' => $post['user_id'], 'date' => $date];
            }
```